# New Spring: How were these characters' deaths explained?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

At the end of *New Spring* we learn that several people die, and

> The Aes Sedai Merean and Ryne are Darkfriends, and the former murders Brys, his son Diryk and Iselle Arrel.

In addition

> Merean herself is killed by Moiraine and  Ryne is killed by Lan. So, 5 people dead overall.

Moiraine is said to have

> Burnt Merean's body, afterwards taking care of Ryne's.
>
> > Carefully she floated Merean's body over that rail on flows of Air, and down a little,  close to the stone of the mountain. Flows of Fire, and flame enveloped the Black sister, flame so hot there was no smoke, only a thick shimmering in the air, and the occasional crack of a splitting rock. -<sub>*New Spring*, When to Surrender</sub>

**My question is: How were the deaths of these high-profile people explained?**

> What did they tell people who wondered after the abrupt deaths of otherwise perfectly healthy people? (Not to mention the disappearance of an Aes Sedai?) I highly doubt that they published it out to the world that the Black Ajah existed and killed a Lord of Kandor.

Any canon answers (interviews with RJ/BS, something in the books I missed) are welcome.

Comment: Not familiar with New Spring... but that sounds to me like body disposal, and Moiraine is canny enough that no explanation would probably be the best explanation.

Comment: @Radhil That would be my guess too.